# Sequence of independent $\sigma$-algebras

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Suppose that $\mathcal{F}_1,\mathcal{F}_2,\dots$ is a Sequence of independent $\sigma$-algebras.
I am trying to understand why the following $\sigma$-algebras:

$$\sigma(\bigcup_{k=1}^{n}\mathcal{F}_k)\ , \ \sigma(\bigcup_{k=n+1}^{m}\mathcal{F}_k)$$
are independent for every $n$ and $m>n$.

I know it's pretty intuitive, since elements in both of the $\sigma$-algebras are made of intersections / unions of sets from the different $\sigma$-algebras of the sequence. However, proving it formally is currently a problem for me.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $n=2$ and $m=3$. Then the first sigma algebra is generated by
$$
\mathcal{A}=\{A\cap B: A\in \mathcal{F}_1,B\in\mathcal{F}_2\}.
$$
That is, $\sigma(\mathcal{F}_1\cup\mathcal{F}_2)=\sigma(\mathcal{A})$. It is easy to see that $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{F}_3$ are independent (by applying the definition of independence). Therefore, $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$ and $\mathcal{F}_3$ are independent as well ($\pi-\lambda$ theorem). For general $n$ and $m$ use induction.

Comment: Nice answer but I don't really see where the induction comes in: your argument applies to arbitrary $m\geq n$, they key being the $\pi-\lambda$ theorem, which we will need twice.

Comment: Nice, even though the induction is not so straightforward, one can still understand why the general case is true using similiar arguments. Thanks!

Comment: @TairGalili The idea is to apply the same reasoning incrementally, i.e., when $\mathcal{G}$ is independent of $\mathcal{H}$ and $\mathcal{I}$, the first is indepndent of $\mathcal{H}\vee\mathcal{I}$.